# Downgrading MSYS2 to a specific Mingw / gcc version

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2

I have MSYS2 64 bit installed in my system.
When I try to check the gcc version, I am getting the following output.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (Rev9, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

But I want to use a specific mingw version for my project which uses qt library.
When I check my build log and installation folder of my qt project I found this.

```
|Project name: DataManager
|Project version: undefined
|C++ compiler for the host machine: ccache c++ (gcc 4.9.2 "c++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2")
|C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.24
|Program python3 found: YES
|Found qmake: C:\Qt\5.6.3\mingw49_32\bin\qmake.EXE (5.6.3)
```

I am assuming that it uses mingw49_32 version and gcc version 4.9.2.
I would like to use the same gcc version (4.9.2) in MSYS2.

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with MSYS2. Old packages are eventually removed from MSYS2 repos, so even if it had GCC 4.9 at some point in the past, it no longer does. The [earliest available version](http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/i686/) is GCC 9.3.

Even if it was in the repo, you'd have to manually download and install it and all its dependencies, since there's no way to download outdated packages directly from `pacman`.

---

But, I suspect that:

- You already have GCC 4.9 installed in `C:\Qt\5.6.3\mingw49_32\bin`.
- Even if you don't, you might be able to get away with using an up-to-date GCC.

Comment: I am using MSYS2 to build openssl code . And I am using those openssl dll in qt project. I want use the same gcc version in MSYS2 as well. Is there any way to make some change in MSYS2 ? Or there any other way to compile openssl code with gcc 4.9.2?

Comment: @kernel Why are you compiling openssl, when MSYS2 lets you download a prebuilt one? If I were you, I'd start compiling the Qt app with an up-to-date GCC instead.

Comment: What if you just add your GCC 4.9.2 to PATH in MSYS2? It should be able to use it.

Comment: I found that MSYS2's MinGW64's GCC 13.2.0 cannot compile VTK 9.3's valid C++11 code in debug mode.  The linker throws a lot of undefined errors related to methods in template classes.  I have to patch VTK headers in order to move the offending methods to outside the class' declaration.  For me this is a bug which didn't occur with an older MinGW64 in my old notebook.  So, being unable to downgrade is a drawback IMO.

Comment: @PauloCarvalho I'd recommend asking a new question about it. Maybe we'll find a solution, or at least figure out whose bug it is.